# Holomorphic map from punctured half plane to region

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I have been trying to find an holomorphic map from the punctured half plane $$ \Omega_1=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Im(z)>0\} \backslash \{i \} $$ to the region $$ \Omega_2=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: Re(z)<0, -\pi<Im(z)<\pi\} $$ I noticed that $\Omega_2$ is the result of applying $log$ to the unit disk with a slit. The problem is: How do I get out of the punctured plane?

Thanks

Comment: Is the only restriction on the function that it is holomorphic? Then any constant function with constant in $\Omega_2$ works.

Comment: The map has to be onto

Comment: Are you trying to apply the [Riemann Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem)? If so, it doesn't apply here since $\Omega_1$ is not [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space3êf).

Comment: $\Omega_2$ is simply connected. Choose a surjective (e.g., biholomorphic) map from the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ to $\Omega_2$. Identify $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$ with $\Omega_1$. now the composition $\Omega_1\to \Omega_2$ might not be surjective. To get a surjective map, first take your surjecive map $\mathbb{D}\to \Omega_2$ and compose it with a suitably ramified covering of $\mathbb{D}$. Then remove the origin in the last step.

Comment: A similar idea is to take first domain including $i$ so is half plane and then map this and the other domain biholomorphically to the unit disc so $i$ goes to $0$ and then take a Blaschke product of degree two vanishing at the origin once so it is a surjective map from the punctured disc onto the unit disc ($z\frac{2z-1}{2-z}$ works) and compose with the above maps appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following three regions are conformally equivalent.
$$ \Omega_1 (\text{ in your definition} ), \mathbb{D}-\{0\} \text{ and } \mathbb{D}-\{\frac{1}{2}\}.$$
The first region is conformally eqivalent to the second via $z \to \frac{z-i}{z+i}$, and the second is conformally equivalent to the third via $z\to \frac{z-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}z}$.

In addition, $\Omega_2$ in your definition is conformally equiavalent to the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, which is obtained by the Riemann mapping theorem.

You can check that the mapping $\phi(z): z \to z^2$ maps $\mathbb{D}-\{\frac{1}{2}\}$ onto $\mathbb{D}$.